# What is wrong with this script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

So I got this script from this guide:  www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf

```
LOG_DIR=/var/log
ROOT_UID=0
LINES=50
E_XCD=86
E_NOTROOT=87

if [ "$UID" != "$ROOT_UID" ]
then
echo "Must be root to run this script."
exit $E_NOTROOT
fi

if [ -n "$1" ]
then
lines=$1
else
lines=$LINES
fi

cd $LOG_DIR

if [ 'pwd' != "$LOG_DIR" ]
then
echo "Can't change to $LOG_DIR."
exit $E_XCD
fi
```

Now I did sudo su on terminal and echoed $UID which gives me 0. That means my if condition turns out to be false but still I am getting "Must be root to run this script." while running this script.

Also in original script this if condition was given as

```
if [ "$UID" -ne "$ROOT_UID" ]
```

but I was getting Illegal number error because apparently -ne is only used for string so I changed it to !=.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @dan08 $UID is equal to $ROOT_UID so why it is going inside if statement i.e. printing "Must be root to run this script"?

Comment: For shell, within `[...]`, the `!=` operator does string comparison and `-ne` does numeric comparison.

Comment: Note that this `[ 'pwd' !=` should be this ``[ `pwd` !=`` or preferably this `[ $(pwd) !=`, or in bash, this `[ $PWD !=`

Comment: If you were getting "illegal number", then either $UID or $ROOT_UID is not what you think it is. Try echo-ing their values just before the condition.

Comment: @glennjackman Thank you for pwd thing. I was going to post new question for that.

Comment: This is the "Advanced *bash* scripting" guide after all. Run the scripts with `bash`.

Comment: @glennjackman Unlike `$UID`, `$PWD` is not bash-specific. It's [standard for Bourne-style shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html). For example, see [`man dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/dash.1.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of executing it with

```
sh script.sh
```

execute it with

```
bash script.sh
```

(or add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line to set the interpreter).

The `sh` shell in Ubuntu is **not** `bash`, but a separate shell called `dash`. `dash` does not have as many features as `bash`, which makes it more efficient, but these missing features sometimes break scripts intended for `bash`. One such feature is the  `$UID` variable, which is *not defined* in `dash`.

This means that when the script is executed in `dash`, the comparison will become `["" != "0"]`, which evaluates to true no matter what user is running it. However, if it is run in `bash` with root permissions, the strings will be equal, and the script will work.

Comment: Or alternately, declare the interpreter to use by adding `#!/bin/bash` to the top of the script.

Comment: Thanks, I was editing my post to add that when I saw your comment.

Comment: Note that a [hashbang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) at the top of `script.sh` doesn't affect the behavior of `sh script.sh` (nor of `bash script.sh`). `sh ...` always uses `sh` as the interpreter. A hashbang line determines the interpreter of an executable script that is itself [run as a program](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve). To cause `#!...` to be read and used, run `script.sh` with the command `./script.sh` (if it's in the current directory) or just as `/path/to/script.sh`. For this to work, `script.sh` must be marked executable (`chmod +x script.sh` does this).

Answer (score 1):

As [McLovin says](https://askubuntu.com/a/514783/22949), the automatically set, readonly `UID` (and `EUID`) variable is a special feature of [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/bash.1.html) (and some other shells). It's not standard for [Bourne-style shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) and `sh` cannot be assumed to set these variables. In particular, `sh` in Ubuntu is (currently, by default) [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/dash.1.html), which does not set them.

You have two options:

1. Cause your script to be run by `bash` instead of `sh`.
2. Change your script so it's more portable and doesn't require `bash`.

### Running Your Script With `bash`

You haven't told us the name of your script (which is okay). I'm going to call it *`cleanup`*, as that's the name of the similar script in the guide you're working from.

Note in particular that I am *not* calling it something like `cleanup.sh`. This is because I don't recommend you name it with a `.sh` suffix:

- A `.sh` suffix suggests it is compatible with `sh`!
- Most scripts aren't given a suffix at all, and having a `.sh` or `.bash` suffix may even be interpreted as suggesting your file is a "library" rather than a "top level" script. That is, that it provides code to be sourced by other scripts (for example, with the `.` builtin) rather than actually run directly.

However, including a `.sh` suffix will not affect the technical behavior of your script in any way. There is no technical advantage or disadvantage associated with doing so.

**Add a [hashbang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))** as the very first line of your script: `#!/bin/bash`

**Make your script executable** with `chmod +x cleanup`.

Now you can **run your script** by running the command:

- `./cleanup`, when it's in the current directory. (Especially when scripting for education, exploration, testing, fun, or other limited or one-time use, this is perhaps the most common way.)
- `/path/to/cleanup`, in general. If the first word of a command contains a `/` it is interpreted as path to an executable file. (That's the reason for the above `./` syntax, as `.` means the current directory.)

  By *first word* I mean the command up to but not including its first [unescaped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) space or tab:
  `foo-bar/baz` is the first word of `foo-bar/baz qux`, while `spam\ ham` is the first word of `spam\ ham eggs` because the space before `ham` is escaped with a backslash.
- *`cleanup`*, if it's in a directory in your `PATH` (and no directory listed first has an executable of the same name, and it is not superseded by a [shell builtin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin), [function](http://steve-parker.org/sh/functions.shtml), or [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(command))).

Regardless of whether or not a script *`cleanup`* has a `#!...` hashbang line or what that line says:

- `sh cleanup` will still (attempt to) run it with `sh` as the interpreter.
- `bash cleanup` will still (attempt to) run it with `bash` as the interpreter.

This is because, in those cases, you are actually running the interpreter (`sh` or `bash`) and passing the name of the script to the interpreter, to be run. Many programs accept names of files to open on the command line, and shells like `sh` and `bash` follow this convention.

### Making Your Script Portable

If you want to make your script portable, the simplest way is to not use `$UID` at all, and instead use some facility available to all Bourne-style shells.

In general there's no built-in shell facility to determine user ID. But you can use [`id`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/id.1.html). This is an external program rather than a shell builtin, but like [`cat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/cat.1.html) and [`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/ls.1.html), it's reasonable to expect it will be present.

`id` by itself outputs a bunch of info, but `id -u` gives just the effective user ID.

So instead of `if [ "$UID" != "$ROOT_UID" ]`, you can use:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != "$ROOT_UID" ]
```

*Technically*, this is not equivalent. `$UID` in `bash` gives the real user ID, and `id -u` really corresponds to `bash`'s `$EUID`. If you really want the UID and not the EUID, use `id -ru`.